# Homebrew Warning: Xcode is installed to a directory with a space in the name

Tags: xcode, homebrew

I just wiped and reinstalled OSX 10.7.5, I'm attempting to set up Homebrew but receive the following warning.

[image]

I've [seen this blog post](http://blog.daviddemartini.com/archives/4561) on someone having the same problem, but didn't see a link/illustration to his solution included. Any help on how to correct and remove this warning will be well received.

Here is the output from which gcc && echo $PATH?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you retry with a fresh installation using [this link](http://ricardianambivalence.com/2012/10/02/install-homebrew-on-your-mac-a-tutorial/). Let me know if it doesn't work for you. Or, see [this blog post](http://blog.daviddemartini.com/archives/4561). He is talking about the same problem

Comment: the first link you sent me, re installing Xcode to load cli tools worked. Much appreciation, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me was:

```
$ sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app
```

I had pointed it to `/Volume/Macintosh\ HD/Applications/Xcode.app` during the setup process.

Comment: For me this not worked. Changed: `sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode\ 6.0.app/`. After `brew install libiconv` I have error: `(blabla) make install (blabla) builddir="\`pwd\`"; cd libcharset && /Applications/XCode 6.0.app/Content/(blabla) /bin/sh: Applications/Xcode: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 2):

I ended up needing to do both the things suggested in other responses here; neither one alone would have fixed the problem in my case. I had originally installed Xcode to a subdirectory under Applications, with a space in the directory name. Here's how I fixed it:

1) In Finder I moved Xcode from the folder it was in to the main Applications folder. (I chose to try dragging it, not uninstalling and reinstalling, because I didn't want to wait for it to download again--it's a big file and takes a long time to download.) But when I tried running brew doctor again I got a new error, this time saying that 
"xcrun: error: active developer path ([the previous path to Xcode.app]) does not exist, use `xcode-select --switch path/to/Xcode.app` to specify the Xcode that you wish to use for command line developer tools (or see `man xcode-select`)"

2) So I followed its directions and ran `sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app` to tell it the new location. Success!

(One other thing I did to clean up: I had forgotten that dragging Xcode.app from its subdirectory to the main Applications folder would copy it instead of moving it, so afterward I had two copies. I deleted the one in the subdirectory, since Xcode is currently over 9GB and I wanted the space back.)